# Silverlight 4 Image Source adding through Uri

Tags: image, silverlight-4.0

I am working on a silverlight application and I want add Image source through Code behind
so I am adding image source like this

```
img.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"C:\Users\Jitendra\Pictures\2006-09-11 001\Kamlesh\DSC_0261.JPG", UriKind.Absolute));
```

This will not work.

But look at this into the WPF it's working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your C drive isn't accessible when you run your application. Try adding the image to your project and use a relative URI.

Comment: ok so my scenario is diffent in my case I want to assing path any from the pc so how I can rectify this. or any other alternate for this..thanks..